# after configuring MySQL as a database backend - table projects remains empty

Tags: mysql, location, storage, project, rundeck

Following [this page](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html) I switched from H2 to MySQL DB backend. I wondered that after that, my users and executions vanished, while the project definitions remained.

I see entries in rduser table, but the projects and many others remain empty.

So I wonder why some tables are populated, while others aren't, and perhaps some helpful soul can point me to a ressource where I can read where rundeck stores what.

Thanks in advance! Tom

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you have this line in your `rundeck-config.properties` file (usually at `/etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties` path):

```
rundeck.projectsStorageType=db
```

That allows to store projects in your database. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/configuration.html#storage-types).

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

The article that I pointed to did not mention that parameter - when users move to db storage, it would help.

As I installed and started with the newest version, I wonder why this parameter was not active.

Perhaps storing projects in the DB is not without drawbacks? Changes to project attributes are actually stored as json code in the storage table. The project.properties file was more readable indeed.

Kind regards, Tom

Comment: You can still be using the project properties in your "instance with backend DB" (but now using the Rundeck GUI to access it), just go to "Project Settings"  (left menu) -> "Edit Configuration" -> and click on "Edit Configuration File" (up to right)